# UWP - How to override the default Segoe UI font for RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, fonts, richeditbox

We have a UWP app with a RichEditBox that receives content from an RTF that looks like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2512
\cocoatextscaling1\cocoaplatform1{\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset0 HelveticaNeue;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;\red59\green52\blue26;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;\cssrgb\c23137\c20392\c10196;}
\pard\tx5600\tx6160\tx6720\fi200\slleading21\pardirnatural\partightenfactor0
\f0\fs20 \cf2 Healthy Eating Takes Neighborhood by Storm!}
```

As you can see, the font family is HelveticaNeue, which is not a preinstalled font in Windows 10 machines, and therefore our RichEditBox falls back to the system Segoe UI.

We set the content of the RichEditBox using the following code:

```
string rtfContent = "{\rtf1 [...] by Storm!}"; // the actual content to fill the RichEditBox
RichEditBox myRichEditBox = ...;
myRichEditBox .Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtfContent);
```

Please notice that we cannot modify the input RTF.

We also tried in a simpler PoC, where we set in the XAML:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="myRichEditBox1"  FontFamily="Algerian" Width="500" Height="300"/>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void TestRtfFonts()
{
    string rtf = "{\\rtf1\\fbidis\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\nouicompat\\deflang2057{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fswiss\\fprq2\\fcharset0 Helvetica Neue;}}{\\colortbl ;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;}{\\*\\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\nowidctlpar\\tx720\\cf1\\f0\\fs21 I would like to see this text in Algerian}";
    myRichEditBox1.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
    {
        myRichEditBox1.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtf);
    };
}
```

The graphical result of this test is this one:
[image]

This obviously shows that the RichEditBox is not working properly...

Is there a way to tell UWP to use another font (e.g. Verdana) rather than Segoe UI, or, even better, a custom font that I embed in the app as App resource?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look here => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox?view=winrt-20348. With ITextSelection you should also be able to change the Font itself

Comment: Thanks @thezapper but we load the RTF string using SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtfContent), and the RTF can also be complex (e.g. with several tokens with different fonts, font sizes etc.), so I am not completely sure how to use the ITextSelection in this case. Could you provide a sample code of your idea please?

Comment: As mentioned in Discord, I can't reproduce this. Simply setting the control's FontFamily prior to loading the RTF containing `\fcharset0 HelveticaNeue;` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could set FontFamily property directly like `richEditBox.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas")`.

For the custom font, you could download it and add it to the Assets folder of the project(right click **Assets**->**Add**->**Existing Item**->your font file).
The property of this font file should be:

- Build action - Content
- Copy to Output directory - Copy if newer

Usage:

```
<RichEditBox FontFamily= "Assets/customfont.ttf#font name"/>
```

My sample:

```
<RichEditBox x:Name="myRichEditBox1"  FontFamily="Assets/Helvetica-Neue-2.ttf#Helvetica Neue" />
```

**Update:**

I can reproduce your issue. You only need to set fontfamily after loading text like the following.

```
myRichEditBox1.Loaded += (sender, args) =>
    {
        myRichEditBox1.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, rtf);
myRichEditBox1.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Algerian");
//myRichEditBox1.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Assets/Helvetica-Neue-2.ttf#Helvetica Neue");
    };
```

Comment: Hi Arya. thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can put whatever I want as richEditBox.FontFamily, but the fallback font is always Segoe UI. Any other idea?

Comment: I have tested, it works well on my side. HelveticaNeue font is similar to the Segoe UI, you could use two richEditBox to compare the difference of font. If the question is still not resolved, could you please provide us your sample through GitHub or OneDrive?

Comment: Hi Arya, I updated my question adding also a small excerpt of the PoC that we tried. Actually what you propose was our first attempt... Unfortunately, for our standards, Helvetica IS NOT similar to Segoe UI! The width of the characters is pretty different and this results in a flow of the text that in several cases is pretty different. So if you state that it is working well because SEgoe is similar to Helvetica, unfortunately this is not an acceptable solution for us.